# Switch template based on parent property. Possible?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, bing-maps

Here is my scenario. Working with Bing Map control(MVVM):

```
<m:Map x:Name="MainMap"
            ZoomLevel="{Binding MapZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}"
            LogoVisibility="Collapsed"
            CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed"
            CredentialsProvider="{Binding BingApiKey}"
            UseInertia="True" 
            Mode="Road" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="5">
            <m:MapItemsControl 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WorkLayerData}}">
                <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}"
                                Background="LightPink"  BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayId}" />    
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </m:MapItemsControl>
        </m:Map>
```

On a bottom you see how I bind my "custom" pushpins by simply declaring `DataTemplate` with Border and TextBlock.

What I want is to declare 3 templates for the same item and choose them based on `ZoomLevel` property of `MainMap`

For example, when ZoomLevel<=3 I willdisplay small dots, when it is between 3 and 8 I will display more fancy pushpin with ID and when it's 8+ I may display even more info.

It's a simple idea but I'd like to know if possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at a [DataTemplateSelector](http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/09/28/datatemplateselector-in-silverlight.aspx) solution for Silverlight.